# How to turn this JavaScript string "myArray[0].myPrice" in to a reference to myPrice?

Tags: javascript

If I have a string of `"myArray[0].myPrice"`, how do I turn this in to a reference to `myPrice`?

This is the code context:

```
binding.value = convert(binding.data[binding.field], 
                        binding.converter, binding.data, elem);
```

`binding.field` is what contains "myArray[0].myPrice".

`binding.data` has a reference to the hierarchical object which has an Array property of myArray, and the first element is an object with a property of myPrice.

EDIT: based on the answers, this worked:

```
binding.value = convert(eval('(binding.data.' + binding.field + ')'), 
              binding.converter, binding.data, elem);
```

Is it good to use eval like this?  I thought eval was going away in newer JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you have it in a string?

Comment: The framework we are using takes a name and references the object, but it doesn't like "myArray[0].myPrice", so we want to modify the framework to allow us to pass it.

Comment: Why would it like the string version?  Why would you HAVE the string version of that?  Doing it that way is probably a bad idea.

Comment: what context is myArray defined in? is there a window.myArray? if myArray is defined as a private variable in the current context you wont be able to extract the value, make sure you can refer to it from window (ie create a reference such as window.AppData.myArray)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval`, but here is a better solution:

```
// The following code results in the same as that scary eval(...)

var data = binding.data,
    chain = binding.field.split(/[\.\[\]]+/);

for (var i = 0; data[chain[i]]; i++) {
    data = data[chain[i]];      
}

// Embrace JavaScript Awesomeness!
```

A breakdown of what I'm doing here:

In JS any property can be called as `object[propertyName]`.

That includes arrays, i.e. `a[3]` is the same as `a['3']`.

Therefore, we split the string using one of the characters: `.`, `[`, `]`. The `+` is there because without it if you have `a[3].b[3]` the `].` will give you an empty 
string.

We might get an empty string in the end, but that's not a problem since `""` is like `false` in JS.

You could go further and filter out all the invalid variable names, which in javascript is a name that does not conform to `[a-zA-Z_$][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*`. But I am not quite sure as to why one would do that...

Comment: I added a possible solution based on your comment.  How would you do it without eval?

Comment: Awesome, you don't need to use eval after all

Comment: oh hold on, I'll fix my answer, see your problem here

Comment: Interestingly, a[3] and a['3'] are only the same because '3' is converted to numeric before a[] gets a hold of it.  For example, a['1+2'] is a property of the array, where a[3] is an element.  Very nice answer btw.

Comment: thanks, I updated it so as to not use if. surrender should be unconditional. btw '1+2' is not a valid JS name, although browsers support all sorts of crazy stuff. and there is some magic for a['3'] as well, i am not really sure how that one is implemented...

Comment: I didn't think "myArray[0].myPrice" was valid either until today.  LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it ain't exactly pretty, but it doesn't use `eval`:

```
var str = 'myArray[0].myPrice';
var parts = str.split(/[\[\].]+/);
doSomething(window[parts[0]][parts[1]][parts[2]]);
```

where `window[parts[0]][parts[1]][parts[2]]` is the actual reference.  Not sure why you'd have a string version **and** one loaded into memory, though.

Comment: No need for `parseInt` — in JS, `foo[5]` and `foo["5"]` refer to the same array element.

Comment: Ah, true... paranoid habit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the current context, this might work:

```
eval("myArray[0].myPrice")
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var a = eval("myArray[0].myPrice".split('.')[1]);
```

However this will probably not work in the context you run it in since `myPrice` will be referring to `window.myPrice` which I doubt would be defined as anything.

Your best bet here is to define `myArray` in a scope that can be accessed from anywhere (such as  `window.AppNS.Data.myArray`) and then use the `eval()` function to access this.

```
var a = eval("window.AppNS.Data." + "myArray[0].myPrice") 
alert(a) // the contents of myPrice are revealed
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar to the logic we use in the template engine [pure.js](http://beebole.com/pure)

```
var obj = {
    myArr:[
        {price:15}
    ],
    anObj:{
        prop:'ABC'
    }
};
function getRef(o, path){
    var props = path.split(/\./),
        prop,
        isArr = /([^\[]+)(\[(\d+)\])*/,
        i = 0, ii = props.length;
    while(i < ii){
        prop = props[i].match(isArr);
        o = o[prop[1]];
        if(prop[2]){
            o = o[+prop[3]];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return o;
}
console.log(getRef(obj, 'myArr[0].price')); // --> 15
console.log(getRef(obj, 'anObj.prop')); // --> ABC
```